# How to play the video using media module?

Tags: media, files

I am using drupal 7 and i am in need of upload a video from our local system as well as from the video. I found the media module and media_youtube module. After installing the module, the url from the youtube is working, but for local machine system video upload in getting downloadable option in the front end and not played.

How to play the video without downloadable option in the same page. Please suggest me some ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can see see [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/168009#player) the list of player modules that extend media module.
There is also basic version information about each module.

Start with [jPlayer](http://drupal.org/project/jplayer) and see if it fits your needs.